# How do I find out if I have the C libraries?

Tags: c, libraries

I am trying some code and it does staff only from main function. So I believe the string.h it's missing on my system. How do I check where and what C libraries do I have on my Linux system. If the libraries are not there what command shall I type to download them.

Thanks

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char tracks[] [80] =
    {
        "I left my heart in Harvard Med School",
        "Newark, Newark - a wonderful town",
        "Dancing with a Dork",
        "From here to maternity",
        "The girl from Iwo Jima"
    };

void find_track(char search_for[])
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (strstr(tracks[i], search_for))

                printf("Track %i: '%s'\n", i, tracks[i]);
            }
    }

int main()
    {
        char search_for[80];
        printf("Search for: ");
        fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
        find_track(search_for);
        return 0;
    }
```

And no complain from the compiler. It asks: Search for: I type the string press enter and it gets out of the program.

```
vincent@hp500iq-it:~/c/code/ch2$ gcc strstr.c -o strstr && ./strstr
Search for: town
vincent@hp500iq-it:~/c/code/ch2$ gcc strstr.c -o strstr && ./strstr
Search for: Dancing with a Dork
vincent@hp500iq-it:~/c/code/ch2$
```

Comment: Did you put `#include <string.h>` into your code? Did the compiler complain about not finding `string.h`?

Comment: Please, write the error and your code..

Comment: If the program links, i.e. the compiler can produce an executable, all needed libraries were found. (With dynamic linking, which happens on modern systems unless you specify -static when you build, you may encounter runtime errors, but right when you try to run the program.) In this case it's the C standard library which doesn't need to be mentioned explicitly in the link command (on the contrary, you must say if you _don't_ want it, e.g. when building your own compiling environment).

Answer (score 3):

First, you type in `town`, and press enter, the enter is captured as part of the input.

Then, when you use the `strstr` function, it tries to find `Newark, Newark - a wonderful town` within string `town[enter]`.  Naturally, that does not match.

---

When you type in `Dancing with a Dork`, and press enter, the enter is captured as part of the input.

Then, when you use the `strstr` function, it tries to find `Dancing with a Dork[enter]` within string `Dancing with a Dork`.  Naturally, that does not match.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to pass the string without pressing Enter?

Comment: Use scanf("%s", search_for).

Comment: If I use scanf then can not put spaces between words.